# How to run single scenario in eclipse with qaf bdd editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, bdd, qaf

I am using [bdd implementation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) provided by [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) for test automation and using [qaf-bdd-editors](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/qaf-bdd-editors) eclipse plugin for development. I am able to run my scenarios using [xml configuration](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html) file but to run specific single scenario need to modify confirmation file each time. Is there any easier way to run selected scenario in editor without modifying configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing below trick:

1. Create generic configuration file. Let say `config/selectionrun_config.xml`

```
<suite name="QAF Demo">
    <test name="BDD Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[
       System.getProperty("selection","").length()==0 || testngMethod.getMethodName().equalsIgnoreCase(System.getProperty("selection","").trim())
       ]]></script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory" />
            <class
                name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

2. Create [TestNG configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDMoU.png) let say "RUN_SELECTED_SCENARIO"

   1. Give configuration name:  `RUN_SELECTED_SCENARIO`
   2. set suite : `config/selectionrun_config.xml`
   3. select arguments tab and [set vm arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwDdf.png)

```
     -Dscenario.file.loc="${selected_resource_loc}" -Dselection="${selected_text}"
```

3. Now to run any single scenario (bdd or gherkin) open file in editor and select scenario name (normal text selection in editor), [right-click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTqyW.jpg) -> run As -> Run Configuration -> "RUN_SELECTED_SCENARIO". If you want to run all scenarios in file, don't select scenario name and run.

You also can select scenario in editor and directly run by [Run button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpG61.png) in top navigation.

Comment: It worked!... Thanks for the trick. It worked for entire file   as wells as for selected scenario.

Comment: Above example uses `equalsIgnoreCase` for scenario section. instead of that you can use `contains`. For instance, 

   > System.getProperty("selection","").length()==0 || testngMethod.getMethodName().contains(System.getProperty("selection","").trim())

Comment: It's not working for me! Checked on windows 10 system               `===============================================
QAF Demo
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================`

Comment: Will you try adding bsh dependency. For example if you are using maven,  add 
 ```<dependency>
   <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
   <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
   <version>2.0b4</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.beanshell/bsh-core -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
   <artifactId>bsh-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.0b4</version>
  </dependency>```

Comment: After adding bsh-core dependancy along with bsh, it is working for windows as well..===============================================
QAF Demo
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: After Adding mentioned dependency it's working fine. 
Thanks