# QAF Perfecto - Not able to consume test data from XML

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, qaf, perfecto

When trying to consume data from XML in the project in Quantum Perfecto, I am getting Lexing error. I have attached the scenario with this and the error.

Evern the same error is seen in quantum starter kit project too.

```
@GettingToKnowYou
Feature: Verify the Borrower can Navigate through Getting To Know You Pages

   @GKY @Test
 Scenario Outline: Verify Borrower complete Getting To Know You Page

   Given User already Signed with "<emailaddress>" and "<password>" 

    Examples: {'key' : 'blenddata.borrower.dataset'}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided details of the editor you are using. This looks like error from editor and not related to quantum project. I hope you will be able to run your test without any issue. You can try using [qaf bdd editors](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/qaf-bdd-editors).

Furthermore you can start using [BDD2 syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) instead of Gherkin. BDD2 is advanced syntax and compatible with most of the gherkin editors. In BDD2 syntax your feature file may look like below:

```
@GettingToKnowYou
Feature: Verify the Borrower can Navigate through Getting To Know You Pages

 @GKY @Test
 @key:blenddata.borrower.dataset
 Scenario Outline: Verify Borrower complete Getting To Know You Page

   Given User already Signed with "<emailaddress>" and "<password>"
```

In run [configuration](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html) for feature files which is written in BDD2 you need to use BDDTestFactory2

Comment: Thanks ! Will try that and let you know. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Hello @user861594 I have installed the cucmber and qaf editors from below sites. I am still seeing the issue. 
https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/editor/bdd/eclipse/                                                                                     
http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/

Comment: try right click ->open with and open with qaf gherkin editor.

Comment: Thanks ! I have no issues in opening. I have issue while running as cucumber feature file. When trying to run I am getting the messgae I have mentioned in my question at top - Lexing error

Comment: Are you running using cucumber runner? If so try running with [qaf runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048141/how-to-run-single-scenario-in-eclipse-with-qaf-bdd-editor).